# Foursqaure2 API V2 Login Error

Tags: iphone, foursquare

I am trying to login for foursquare using foursquare api. it is showing login page but crashing when I am trying to enter username or password . It was working well before some days but suddenly stop working.

```
Server responded with:400, bad request
2012-08-24 14:44:25.227[1962:17903] contant data {"error":"invalid_grant"}
2012-08-24 14:44:25.228[1962:17903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value (key: foursquare_access_token)'
```

Please help me . Why this error is coming ?

Answer (score 3):

Foursquare login page now returns a requests from Facebook website. 
So you could login into Foursquare using FB credentials.

One of those responses brakes the **Foursquare2** logic
https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=10#cb=xxx&origin=https%3A%2F%2Ffoursquare.com%2Fxxx&domain=foursquare.com&relation=parent&frame=xxx&**error=unknown_user**

Foursquare2 is looking for the "error=" in the response. And it performs a delegate call-back if it finds it.

To fix it replace your 
' webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:'

in Foursquare2.m with

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSString *url =[[request URL] absoluteString];

    if ([url rangeOfString:@"facebook.com"].location != NSNotFound)
        return YES; //ignore Facebook authentication

    if ([url rangeOfString:@"code="].length != 0) {

        NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
        NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
        for (cookie in [storage cookies]) {
            if ([[cookie domain]isEqualToString:@"foursquare.com"]) {
                [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
            }
        }

        NSArray *arr = [url componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
        [delegate performSelector:selector withObject:[arr objectAtIndex:1]];
        [self cancel];
    }else if ([url rangeOfString:@"error="].length != 0) {
        NSArray *arr = [url componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
        [delegate performSelector:selector withObject:[arr objectAtIndex:1]];
        FourSquareLog(@"Foursquare: %@",[arr objectAtIndex:1]);
    } 
    return YES;
}
```

Notice a new

```
if ([url rangeOfString:@"facebook.com"].location != NSNotFound)
    return YES; //ignore Facebook authentication
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it was very helpful. I was wondering, what would do to make the login with facebook button to properly work? with your solution once I press the button the screen goes blank and nothing loads.

Comment: but what if I don't want to ignore Facebook authentication ? I want to login in foursquare from Facebook then?

Answer (score 0):

Get yout own key consumer key and secret for application on [oauth](http://foursquare.com/oauth/)

After having consumer key and secret  for application update or replace in

```
 Constants.h file of your poject
```